# when passing df$var to a function, is it possible to get the name of 'var'?

Tags: r, nse

I'm writing a function where I'd like to be able to pass in variables from a data frame as atomic vectors, like `df$var` (e.g., `mtcars$mpg`).

To keep the example very simple, say the function just returns `data.frame(table(df$var))`:

```r
foo.function <- function(var) {
  data.frame(table(var))
}

head(foo.function(mtcars$mpg))
#>    var Freq
#> 1 10.4    2
#> 2 13.3    1
#> 3 14.3    1
#> 4 14.7    1
#> 5   15    1
#> 6 15.2    2
```

Notice that the name of the tabulated variable in the returned table is the internal name of the passed object (`var`) rather than it's "original" name, which was `mpg`. Is it possible to retrieve `mpg` (just the name) from within the function (without changing or adding arguments)? I was inclined to say no, since R is just receiving a vector of values, but I suspect R may have this capacity based on what it can do with [NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `deparse/substitute` to extract the column name

```
foo.function <- function(var) {
   print(sub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(var))))
   data.frame(table(var))
  }

head(foo.function(mtcars$mpg), 4)
#[1] "mpg"
#   var Freq
#1 10.4    2
#2 13.3    1
#3 14.3    1
#4 14.7    1
```

---

If we need to change the column name

```
foo.function <- function(var) {
  nm1 <- sub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(var)))
  out <- data.frame(table(var))
  names(out)[1] <- nm1
  out
 }

head(foo.function(mtcars$mpg), 4)
#  mpg Freq
#1 10.4    2
#2 13.3    1
#3 14.3    1
#4 14.7    1
```

As @RonakShah noted in the comments, it is better to pass column names and data as separate arguments.  If the limitation of the function is to pass only a single argument and it always have to be with `$`, then the above function would be able to retrieve the column name

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was possible somehow. Does `deparse(substitute())` have a `tidy` equivalent? I thought I read somewhere that there was a similar function in `rlang` or `lazyeval` but I might be mistaken.

Comment: I agree it's better to pass as two arguments. I'm writing the function to be able to accept both forms `function(df, var)` and `function(df$var)` so I can use both forms in the future while not having to update old code.

Comment: @lost If you are passing as a string column name, then use `sym` to convert to `symbol` and then evaluate with `!!`  or if it is unquoted, then convert to quosure with `enquo` and evaluate with `!!`.  I assume that you would be using tidyverse way i.e. `count`

Comment: @lost I meant something like `foo2 <- function(data, var) {
    var <- enquo(var);
 data %>% count(!! var);
 
};

foo2(mtcars, mpg)`

Comment: Yeah, I'd use something like that, I think. I was trying to look at the code for verbs like `dplyr::filter` for inspiration to see how they handle the variable name input.

Comment: what would be the base R equivalent of that? i.e. with `table` instead of `count`?

Comment: @lost Isn't the first option `base R`

Comment: I meant the base R equivalent of `enquo(var); data %>% count(!! var)` if I was writing the function as `function(data, var)` with `var` unquoted. We can't do `nm <- deparse(substitute(var)); table(data$nm);`

Comment: @lost  try with `table(data[[nm]])`

Comment: @lost I meant `f1 <- function(dat, var) {var1 <- deparse(substitute(var)); table(dat[[var1]])}`